# What are the cons of using mysql's reserved keywords as fields with django?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a Django model as:

```
Class DataFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_upload_path)
```

But, **`file`** is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

I know that we can use any reserved keyword as column name by wrapping it in ``.

My senior advised me not to use reserved keywords and use something which is nearly meaningful other than just file.

What are the cons?

Comment: You can just use `db_column='other_field_name'` to use different ones at the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, `file` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

That is not a problem when you use Django. You can use the [**`db_column=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to use a different name at the database level.

For example:

```
class DataFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_upload_path, db_column='filepath')
```

So now you can access the field at the Django level with `my_data_file.file`, but at the database side, the column is named `filepath`. Django will make thus queries to the `filepath` column.

Comment: Do you know what problems I might face in the future if I use reserved keywords? Ignore django.

Comment: @spiritsree: please don't use reserved keywords for the database level. It makes it a lot easier to make mistakes later. For example if you write another program that works with the database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378/67579